# How to extend Visual Studio with TFS to override the Get command

Tags: c#, visual-studio, plugins, tfs, accurev

I am working on a conversion from Accurev to TFS and am being blocked by Accurev's usage of symbolic links, which TFS does not work with.  I have tried several methods, but they all seem to fail to work.

What I would like to do is have a file in the project/branch that lists all the linked files and folders that is stored in source control.  On every get operation, I would like to read this file and link the folders and files specified in the central file.  However, I cannot find a way to extend the get operation.  Does anyone have any experience in extending it in VS?

Answer (score 2):

TFS does not provide a way to extend what happens on a Get action. You could easily create a custom powershell or batch file that you use in place of calling `tf.exe`, but since Team Build and Visual Studio call into TFS directly using the Client Object Model you're not going to make this easy on yourself.

In the end everything is possible of course. You could write a custom build action for Team Build to replace the standard get operation, or create one that triggers after the standard get operation has completed. You can write a `vsix` visual studio extension that replaces the standard Get operation everywhere in the menu's of Visual Studio and get to a something that could be considered workable. But I would not recommend this. It is far from standard and it is far from sustainable. You'll have to unwire so much default behavior in Visual Studio (that checks out files that are changed, adds files to source control when they're added to the project file etc etc etc).

SourceSafe used to have this feature as well (it was called pinning) and Microsoft removed it when they created TFVC. They now recommend you use [branching and merging to synchronize these files across multiple projects,](http://www.wug.cz/praha/akce/GetFile.ashx?EventStoredFileID=77) making sure that the source structure in Source control is the same as the ones on disk during build.

You can [also make use of the Add-as-Link option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in your project files. This allows you to keep the original files in their original location, but MsBuild will understand that in the project structure this file actually lives somewhere else. Or package the linked files up in a NuGet package and use the [Dependency Management using NuGet guide](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/releases) to help you place the files in the right location during build.

And finally, you can get very creative using Workspace Mappings, many people never get further than mapping `$/project` -> `$(SourceDir)`, but in essence the workspace mapping is like the file you describe. A way to layout your sources from Source control to disk. You could do:

> `$/Project/DEV/MyProject` -> `$(SourceDir)\MyProject`
>
> `$/Project/Shared/FilesToCopy` -> `$(SourceDir)\Shared`

And you can even add files from other projects in the same collection:

> `$/AnotherProject/Shared` -> `$(SourceDir)\MoreShared`

And something not many people know, you can layout individual files:

> `$/AnotherProject/CompanyAssemblyInfoItems.cs` -> `$(SourceDir)\CompanyAssemblyInfoItems.cs`

The only thing you cannot do, is map files to be children of an already mapped folder. In that case you might need to have the workspace mapping do the fetching of the sources and then a `.targets` file that you include in your `.csproj` file to do the copying of files.